# Angular: p-confirmDialog, backdrop

Tags: angular, primeng

I have p-confirmDialog in my html. However, when I click on the delete button, a backdrop or grey out is shown in front of the p-confirmDialog, and I can not click the p-confirmdialog buttons. The other item in the HTML is a p-datatable. Any idea how to solve this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: can you attach screenshot or code something

Comment: you need to check z-index of your p-confirmDialog by inspecting code in your browser

Comment: Can you please create a Plunker or at least share your HTML and TS component code ?

Comment: @pArthsavadiya, adding z-index brings up the p-confirmDialog, however, when it close, the overlay still covers the background.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I had more than one p-confirmDialog in the module, I removed them and add just one to the root of the module where I had router-outlet.